# Sql Server data extraction (java jdbc): process hangs during retrieving rows

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, bcp

I need to extract data from a remote Sql server database. I am using the [mssql jdbc driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).
I noticed that often dwhen retrieving rows from the database the process suddenly hangs, giving no errors. It remains simply stuck and no more rows are processed.

The code to read from the database is the following:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.10.28:1433;databaseName=MYDB;user=MYUSER;password=MYPWD;selectMethod=direct;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;responseBuffering=adaptive;";

String query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";

try (Connection sourceConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    Statement stmt = sourceConnection.createStatement(SQLServerResultSet.TYPE_SS_SERVER_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY, SQLServerResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)   ) {

    stmt.setFetchSize(100); 
    resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (resultSet.next()) {

        // Often, after retrieving some rows, process remains stuck here

    }

}
```

Usually the connection is established correctly, some rows are fetched, than at some point the process can become stuck in retrieving the next rows batch, giving no errors and not processing any new row. This happens some times, other times it completes succesfully.

AFAIK the only reason I can see is that at some point a connection problem occurs with the remote machine, but shouldn't I be notified of this from the driver?

I am not sure how I should handle these type of situations...is there anything I can do on my side to let the process complete even if there is a temporary connection problem with the remote server (of course if the connection is not recoverable there is nothing I can do)?

As another test, instead of the java jdbc driver I've tried the [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to extract data from the remote database and even with this native utility I can observe the same problem: sometimes it completes succesfully, other times it retrieves some rows (say 20000) and then becomes stuck, no errors and no more rows processed.

Comment: If you have the problem both in Java and bcp, then it is not a problem with those bcp or Java, but with the database server. I would sooner think of row-level locks etc interfering. You should really provide a [mcve].

Comment: You can run sql server prifiler and see what's happening during the process. .maybe there is a lock or a normal wait..also you can use activity monitor to see you what has held your process up..